# Simple Net Scanner Only works Wireless but not wired

Tags: c#, .net, networking, ip

I found this  C# code for simple IP net scanner which scans the connected hosts in the network and displays its physical address and IP address.It works well but only when connected with the network via WIFI. It doesn't work when connected through the network via wires.

```
[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
```

At first, `iphlpapi.dll` has been imported. So, can you explain it? the rest of the code is given below.

```
// Use Your work Group WinNT://&&&&(Work Group Name)
DirectoryEntry DomainEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + this.TxtWorkGroup.Text.Trim());
DomainEntry.Children.SchemaFilter.Add("computer");


// To Get all the System names And Display with the Ip Address
foreach (DirectoryEntry machine in DomainEntry.Children)
{
    string[] Ipaddr = new string[3];
    Ipaddr[0] = machine.Name;

    System.Net.IPHostEntry Tempaddr = null;

    try
    {
        Tempaddr = (System.Net.IPHostEntry)Dns.GetHostByName(machine.Name);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect with the system :" + machine.Name);
        continue;
    }
IPAddress[] TempAd = Tempaddr.AddressList;
    foreach (IPAddress TempA in TempAd)
    {
        Ipaddr[1] = TempA.ToString();

        byte[] ab = new byte[6];
        int len = ab.Length;

        // This Function Used to Get The Physical Address
        int r = SendARP((int)TempA.Address, 0, ab, ref len);
        string mac = BitConverter.ToString(ab, 0, 6);

        Ipaddr[2] = mac;
    }

ListViewItem TempItem = new ListViewItem(Ipaddr);

    this.ListHostIP.Items.Add(TempItem);
}


}
```

Comment: It seems really unlikely to me that the method of connection alone would be the cause - I would focus on whether that is really true or not.

Comment: Have a look here for what iphlpapi is all about: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358(v=vs.85).aspx Do oyu get an exception with above code?

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible to bring changes to this code so it can display the results while connected via wires. If yes, how can I do it? please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the WIFI adapter and try it again.